# VB.NET 2005 website becoming unresponsive

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am working on a website built in VB.NET 2005. It has a data entry page which has a button -- "Save", clicking on which inserts the data in the database ( SQL Server ). The website responds well for the first 10-12 clicks on the button but after that when the user attempts to save data 13th time, the page / website becomes unresponsive for some time i.e. it hangs. What can the possible reasons / remedies for the same??

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start by profiling where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Jeroenh, can you please explain in detail so that I can try the same ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s0xxa1d.aspx

Comment: Thanks for providing the link Jeroenh. I will go through the same and see if I get any solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

Check below points:

1. Your code is disposing all the objects using to connect and insert records into database.
2. Check WebPage size; is it increasing on every save button click?
   (You might be storing data into viewstate before inserting into database.)
3. Check request frequency on web server.
4. Check if the table in which you insert records is being locked by some other process.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are disposing correctly all the connections, datareaders, commands, datadapter.. Also, check for strings been concatenated and substitute it for StringBuilders.. It seem like your system is paging memory to disk..